# Pass event handler from elm to JS through port

Tags: javascript, elm, ffi

In JS we have a function like this:

```
const handleClick = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // some more code
}

<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add to bag</button>
```

My Elm code:

> main.elm

```
port addToBag : Value -> Cmd msg

type Msg
  = ClickBag Item

update msg model =
  case msg of
   ClickBag item ->
      let
        data =
          Encode.object
            [ ("price", Encode.string item.price)
            , ("sku", Encode.string item.sku)
            ]
      in
        ( model, addToBag data )

view model =
  button [onClick ClickBag model.item] [text "Add to bag"]
```

> index.html

```
<div id="elm"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  const addToBag = (params, btnSelector = null) => {
    console.log('json data', params)
  }

  const ElmApp = Elm.Main.init(document.getElementById('elm'))

  ElmApp.ports.addToBag.subscribe(addToBag)

</script>
```

For now, I can get the `params` value but don't know how to pass the event handler(like `event` in JS code) from Elm file to JS through `port`(pass that value to `btnSelector`), 
so I can use that value for the legacy code. Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In Elm you do stopPropagation with https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Events#preventDefaultOn. I can't immediately thing of a reason to use a port. But note that you can pass Json.Values through a port and these can be highly complex things - never seen it used for events, but have used it for e.g. google maps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the full event object as a `Value` and pass that through the port.

```
port toJS : Value -> Cmd msg

onClickWithValue : (Value -> msg) -> Attribute msg 
onClickWithValue toMsg =
    on "click" (Json.map toMsg Json.value)
```

and in `update` have something like

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        SomeTag value ->
            ( { model | count = model.count + 1 }, toJS value )
```

on a side note, if the values you pass to JS are basic values (Bool, Int, Float, String, Maybe, Json.Decode.Value and List, Array, tuples or records of the previous types) , you can just pass them as a record. So, in your case, you can have:

```
type alias Item = 
    { price: String 
    , sku: String 
    }

port addToBag : (Item, Value) -> Cmd msg

type Msg
  = ClickBag Item Value

view model =
  button [onClickWithValue (ClickBag model.item)] [text "Add to bag"]

update msg model =
  case msg of
   ClickBag item value ->
        ( model, addToBag ( item, value ) )
```